# How to detect that a Window has used up its "ShowDialog" call

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF you get to call `ShowDialog` on a window exactly once.  After that it is done for.

Seems kind of lame to me, but those are the rules.  If you call `ShowDialog` again you get this exception:

> Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed

What I want to know is: How can I take a `Window` (or `UserControl` really) and check to see if it has had `ShowDialog` called (so I know to `new` up a different one before calling `ShowDialog` again).

Something like this:

```
public void ShowListOfClients()
{
    //    |  This is the method I want to write
    //    V                                          
    RefreshViewIfNeeded(_myWindowOrUserControlThatShowsAList);

    FillWindowWithBusinessData(_myWindowOrUserControlThatShowsAList);
    _myWindowOrUserControlThatShowsAList.ShowDialog();

}
```

**NOTE:** Clearly in the above example it would be easier to just create a new `WindowOrUserControlThatShowsAList` every time I enter the method.  But please consider the question more that the dumbed down example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't exclusive to ShowDialog(), Show() does it too.  And no, there is no IsDisposed property to check.  IsLoaded is only half a solution, it will be false for the 1st invocation as well.

First approach is to just make a dialog that can be re-shown:

```
    public bool CloseAllowed { get; set; }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
        if (!CloseAllowed) {
            this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

The next one is to explicitly keep track of the health of the object reference:

```
    private Window1 win = new Window1();   // say

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (win == null) {
            win = new Window1();
            win.Closing += delegate { win = null; };
        }
        win.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: I fumbled the last one.  Can't think of a //say fix.

Comment: I like the delegate to the closing method.  That looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: Except that the first suggestion above specifically does not work for modal windows, i.e. with `ShowDialog()`. It will avoid the exception, but it causes other problems, such as not being able to exit the process, and not displaying the window correctly the second time it's made visible. Only the second suggestion (i.e. always recreating the window) is viable.

Comment: Changing the first suggestion so that instead of trying to avoid closing the window, it simply tracked _whether_ the window was closed -- i.e. name the property `IsClosed`, and then handle the `Closed` event instead of `Closing`, and set the property value to `true` there -- that would address the stated question directly, i.e. _"How to detect that a Window has used up its “ShowDialog” call"_

Answer (score 3):

Well the dirty way to do it would be to catch the exception.

The clean way to do it would be to show a window with ShowDialog, and destroy (lose reference to, etc) the window when the function returns. The view should not be tightly coupled with the models (you are using MVVM right?) so creating new visual objects for each client view should not be an issue.

Comment: I am using MVVM, but if I do what you suggest then I have my Model creating the view it supports (something I am told MVVM frowns on).

Comment: If a model needs to be updated on screen, it should fire an event. This event can be attached to by a view. This view may be the owner window, which pends the actual viewing off to a separate dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to deal with this problem without messing up with the Closing event :

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private SomeCustomWindow _someCustomWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnOpenCustomWindowButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_someCustomWindow != null)
            _someCustomWindow.Close();
        _someCustomWindow = new SomeCustomWindow();

        _someCustomWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_someCustomWindow!= null)
            _someCustomWindow.Close();
    }
}
```